# Recent Badges Styling

Tags: bug, design, badges

I was having a quick look at [badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges), when I noticed some minor styling that could be improved with the ***Recent Badges*** displayed in the right hand column:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

**Issues:**

1. Longer names cause the name to be wrapped under the badge.
2. Badges link to the badge related activity of the user but are repeated unnecessarily when they could shown once like a header.

**Proposal:**

I guess the width of that panel isn't going to be changed for this, so I was thinking that a single header badge per group could be shown with a simple badge or other icon beside each user that earned it, so the links persist.

I've come up with the following alternative, using a simple "link" icon, similar to the one used on the toolbar when posting questions/answers:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Two links are required per row, as the first link navigates to [badge activity related to the user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/144/mortarboard?userid=57475) and the second navigates directly to the [user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57475/tanner). Using a simple bullet point (as suggested in comments) wouldn't maintain both links and identify that there are 2 places you can navigate to.

Hopefully the new suggestion is less obtrusive and helps distinguish the header badges from the people that have received them.

Comment: Whoa, all those empty badges people got!

Comment: @Oded my css hacks :-) does look a bit odd, but was trying to think of a way to avoid names wrapping under badges.

Comment: This is a good proposal, however those empty badges bug me. Couldn't they be just bullets? (Unordered list)

Comment: I don't think that the wrapping around is a big enough deal to make that change. The empty badges look worse than having the names wrap around...the section is called "Recent Badges", so you should be able to see the badge name...

Comment: I would rather the column just be widened to take advantage of the fact that people use widescreen monitors in the 21st century

Comment: You don't even need the empty badges, except if you want to group tag badges together (but I guess the tag badges don't often get awarded in groups).

Comment: @nicael - I like the idea of bullets only under the badge 'heading'. If gold/silver/bronze bullets have sufficient contrast against the regular background without the black pseudo-button, all the better.

Comment: @Oded does the updated image help with "all those empty badges"?

Comment: But why those links icons? Just bullets...

Comment: @nicael read the second from last paragraph.

Comment: This design suggestion should get a big thumbs up from the relational database crowd.

Comment: Something about the grouping in this proposal is just SO AWESOME. It's not even absolutely necessary but man it would be so cool to see recent badges with a deliberate removal of redundancy. I guess @Jeeped I'm just a relational nut.