# Users with long names overflow the recent badges list

Tags: bug, design, badges

On the badges page people with names longer than 13 characters overflow on to the next line.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recent Badges Styling](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286261/recent-badges-styling) (MSO) and [Username alignment issue in Recent Badges section](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251586/username-alignment-issue-in-recent-badges-section) (MSE)